# java : Can I send an Object (ex: JTree) using UDP ?.

Tags: java, sockets, object, udp, jtree

What Im Looking for is to send an Object a JTree exactly  via DataPacket, the problem is only can recieve a STRING not JTree .

Comment: Look at serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `Object` into `Json` string on one side and convert back to the `Object` from `Json` string on other side. Take a look at [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)